# How to evaluate a tclsh script?

Tags: bash, shell, eval, tcl, uplevel

[tclsh](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl7.6/UserCmd/tclsh.1.html) is a shell containing the TCL commands.

The TCL [`uplevel`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.htm) command evaluates the given TCL script, but it fails to evaluate a tclsh script (which can contain bash commands).

How can I obtain an analogue of [`uplevel`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/uplevel.htm) for the tclsh script?

---

Consider this TCL script:

```
# file main.tcl

proc prompt { } \
{
   puts -nonewline stdout "MyShell > "
   flush stdout
}

proc process { } \
{
   catch { uplevel #0 [gets stdin] } got
   if { $got ne "" } {
       puts stderr $got
       flush stderr
   }
   prompt
}

fileevent stdin readable process

prompt
while { true } { update; after 100 }
```

This is a kind of TCL shell, so when you type `tclsh main.tcl` it shows a prompt `MyShell >` and it acts like you are in *interactive* `tclsh` session. However, you are in *non-interactive* `tclsh` session, and everything you type is evaluated by the `uplevel` command.  So here you can't use bash commands like you can do it int *interactive* tclsh session. E.g. you can't open `vim` right from the shell, also `exec vim` will not work.

What I want is to make `MyShell >` act like interactive `tclsh` session. The reason why I can't just use `tclsh` is the loop at the last line of `main.tcl`: I have to have that loop and everything has to happen in that loop. I also have to do some stuff at each iteration of that loop, so can use `vwait`.

---

**Here is the solution.**
I have found no better solution then to overwrite the `::unknown` function.

```
# file main.tcl

    proc ::unknown { args } \
    {

        variable ::tcl::UnknownPending
        global auto_noexec auto_noload env tcl_interactive

        global myshell_evaluation
        if { [info exists myshell_evaluation] && $myshell_evaluation } {
            set level #0
        }  else {
            set level 1
        }

        # If the command word has the form "namespace inscope ns cmd"
        # then concatenate its arguments onto the end and evaluate it.

        set cmd [lindex $args 0]
        if {[regexp "^:*namespace\[ \t\n\]+inscope" $cmd] && [llength $cmd] == 4} {
        #return -code error "You need an {*}"
            set arglist [lrange $args 1 end]
        set ret [catch {uplevel $level ::$cmd $arglist} result opts]
        dict unset opts -errorinfo
        dict incr opts -level
        return -options $opts $result
        }

        catch {set savedErrorInfo $::errorInfo}
        catch {set savedErrorCode $::errorCode}
        set name $cmd
        if {![info exists auto_noload]} {
        #
        # Make sure we're not trying to load the same proc twice.
        #
        if {[info exists UnknownPending($name)]} {
            return -code error "self-referential recursion in \"unknown\" for command \"$name\"";
        }
        set UnknownPending($name) pending;
        set ret [catch {
            auto_load $name [uplevel $level {::namespace current}]
        } msg opts]
        unset UnknownPending($name);
        if {$ret != 0} {
            dict append opts -errorinfo "\n    (autoloading \"$name\")"
            return -options $opts $msg
        }
        if {![array size UnknownPending]} {
            unset UnknownPending
        }
        if {$msg} {
            if {[info exists savedErrorCode]} {
            set ::errorCode $savedErrorCode
            } else {
            unset -nocomplain ::errorCode
            }
            if {[info exists savedErrorInfo]} {
            set ::errorInfo $savedErrorInfo
            } else {
            unset -nocomplain ::errorInfo
            }
            set code [catch {uplevel $level $args} msg opts]
            if {$code ==  1} {
            #
            # Compute stack trace contribution from the [uplevel].
            # Note the dependence on how Tcl_AddErrorInfo, etc. 
            # construct the stack trace.
            #
            set errorInfo [dict get $opts -errorinfo]
            set errorCode [dict get $opts -errorcode]
            set cinfo $args
            if {[string bytelength $cinfo] > 150} {
                set cinfo [string range $cinfo 0 150]
                while {[string bytelength $cinfo] > 150} {
                set cinfo [string range $cinfo 0 end-1]
                }
                append cinfo ...
            }
            append cinfo "\"\n    (\"uplevel\" body line 1)"
            append cinfo "\n    invoked from within"
            append cinfo "\n\"uplevel $level \$args\""
            #
            # Try each possible form of the stack trace
            # and trim the extra contribution from the matching case
            #
            set expect "$msg\n    while executing\n\"$cinfo"
            if {$errorInfo eq $expect} {
                #
                # The stack has only the eval from the expanded command
                # Do not generate any stack trace here.
                #
                dict unset opts -errorinfo
                dict incr opts -level
                return -options $opts $msg
            }
            #
            # Stack trace is nested, trim off just the contribution
            # from the extra "eval" of $args due to the "catch" above.
            #
            set expect "\n    invoked from within\n\"$cinfo"
            set exlen [string length $expect]
            set eilen [string length $errorInfo]
            set i [expr {$eilen - $exlen - 1}]
            set einfo [string range $errorInfo 0 $i]
            #
            # For now verify that $errorInfo consists of what we are about
            # to return plus what we expected to trim off.
            #
            if {$errorInfo ne "$einfo$expect"} {
                error "Tcl bug: unexpected stack trace in \"unknown\"" {}  [list CORE UNKNOWN BADTRACE $einfo $expect $errorInfo]
            }
            return -code error -errorcode $errorCode  -errorinfo $einfo $msg
            } else {
            dict incr opts -level
            return -options $opts $msg
            }
        }
        }

        if { ( [info exists myshell_evaluation] && $myshell_evaluation ) || (([info level] == 1) && ([info script] eq "")  && [info exists tcl_interactive] && $tcl_interactive) } {
        if {![info exists auto_noexec]} {
            set new [auto_execok $name]
            if {$new ne ""} {
            set redir ""
            if {[namespace which -command console] eq ""} {
                set redir ">&@stdout <@stdin"
            }
            uplevel $level [list ::catch  [concat exec $redir $new [lrange $args 1 end]]  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
            dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
            return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
            }
        }
        if {$name eq "!!"} {
            set newcmd [history event]
        } elseif {[regexp {^!(.+)$} $name -> event]} {
            set newcmd [history event $event]
        } elseif {[regexp {^\^([^^]*)\^([^^]*)\^?$} $name -> old new]} {
            set newcmd [history event -1]
            catch {regsub -all -- $old $newcmd $new newcmd}
        }
        if {[info exists newcmd]} {
            tclLog $newcmd
            history change $newcmd 0
            uplevel $level [list ::catch $newcmd  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
            dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
            return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
        }

        set ret [catch {set candidates [info commands $name*]} msg]
        if {$name eq "::"} {
            set name ""
        }
        if {$ret != 0} {
            dict append opts -errorinfo  "\n    (expanding command prefix \"$name\" in unknown)"
            return -options $opts $msg
        }
        # Filter out bogus matches when $name contained
        # a glob-special char [Bug 946952]
        if {$name eq ""} {
            # Handle empty $name separately due to strangeness
            # in [string first] (See RFE 1243354)
            set cmds $candidates
        } else {
            set cmds [list]
            foreach x $candidates {
            if {[string first $name $x] == 0} {
                lappend cmds $x
            }
            }
        }
        if {[llength $cmds] == 1} {
            uplevel $level [list ::catch [lreplace $args 0 0 [lindex $cmds 0]]  ::tcl::UnknownResult ::tcl::UnknownOptions]
            dict incr ::tcl::UnknownOptions -level
            return -options $::tcl::UnknownOptions $::tcl::UnknownResult
        }
        if {[llength $cmds]} {
            return -code error "ambiguous command name \"$name\": [lsort $cmds]"
        }
        }
        return -code error "invalid command name \"$name\""

    }


proc prompt { } \
{
    puts -nonewline stdout "MyShell > "
    flush stdout
}

proc process { } \
{
    global myshell_evaluation
    set myshell_evaluation true
    catch { uplevel #0 [gets stdin] } got
    set myshell_evaluation false
    if { $got ne "" } {
        puts stderr $got
        flush stderr
    }
    prompt
}

fileevent stdin readable process 

prompt
while { true } { update; after 100 }
```

The idea is to modify the `::unknown` function so that it handles `MyShell` evaluations as the ones of `tclsh` interactive session.

This is an ugly solution, as I am fixing the code of `::unknown` function which can be different for different systems and diferent versions of tcl.

Is there any solution which circumvents these issues?

Comment: I don't understand your question: tclsh *is* Tcl, and you can use uplevel in tclsh. What am I missing? What do you mean that a tclsh scrip can contain bash commands? In an *interactive* tclsh session, the `unknown` command will `exec` an undefined command.

Comment: FWIW, I'd use `vwait forever` instead of that loop, and anything that needs doing periodically would be scheduled (repeatedly) with `after`.

Comment: @DonalFellows You mean `after idle` ? It will be evaluated only once. How can I make a given script to be evaluated after each iteration in `vwait forever`?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750357/how-can-i-make-a-given-script-to-be-evaluated-after-each-iteration-in-vwait-fore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer, I think, would be to use the approach you're using; to rewrite the `unknown` command. Specifically, there is a line in it that checks to make sure the current context is

- Not run in a script
- Interactive
- At the top level

If you replace that line:

```
if {([info level] == 1) && ([info script] eq "") && [info exists tcl_interactive] && $tcl_interactive} {
```

with something that just checks the level

```
if ([info level] == 1} {
```

you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

uplevel does not only evaluate a script, but it evaluates it in the stack context of the caller of the instance where it's executed. It's a pretty advanced command which should be used when you define your own execution control structures, and OFC it's TCL specific - I find myself unable to imagine how a tclsh equivalent should work.

If you just want to evaluate another script, the proper TCL command would be eval. If that other script is tclsh, why don't you just open another tclsh?

Comment: The tclsh analogue of eval will be fine as well.

Comment: The reason why I can't use another tclsh session is that I have to program a kind of tclsh in TCL script.

Answer (score 0):

Vaghan, you *do* have the right solution. Using ::unknown is how tclsh itself provides the interactive-shell-functionality you're talking about (invoking external binaries, etc). And you've lifted that same code and included it in your MyShell.

But, if I understand your concerns about it being an "ugly solution", you'd rather not reset ::unknown ?

In which case, why not just append the additional functionality you want to the end of the pre-existing ::unknown's body (or prepend it - you choose)

If you search on the Tcl'ers wiki for "let unknown know", you'd see a simple proc which demonstrates this. It prepends new code to the existing ::unknown, so you can keep adding additional "fallback code" as you go along.

(apologies if I've misunderstood why you feel your solution is "ugly")

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `unknown` proc, I suggest that you make the changes to evaluate the expresion

```
if {([info level] == 1) && ([info script] eq "") && [info exists tcl_interactive] && $tcl_interactive} {
```

to true.

- `info level`: call your stuff with `uplevel #0 $code`
- `info script`: call `info script {}` to set it to an empty value
- `tcl_interactive`. Simple: `set ::tcl_interactive 1`

so your code would be

```
proc prompt { } {
    puts -nonewline stdout "MyShell > "
    flush stdout
}

proc process { } {
    catch { uplevel #0 [gets stdin] } got
    if { $got ne "" } {
        puts stderr $got
        flush stderr
    }
    prompt
}

fileevent stdin readable process
set tcl_interactive 1
info script {}
prompt
vwait forever
```