# How can I make a given script to be evaluated after each iteration in vwait forever?

Tags: tcl, event-loop

[`vwait forever`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/vwait.htm) runs the events loop until the `exit` command.

I have some stuff to do during each iteration of the event loop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. What you do is schedule regular timer events that do your work. For user interaction, 10 times a second is *quite* regular enough. To schedule regular timer events, use the [`every` command from the Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9299), like this:

```
proc every {ms body} {after $ms [info level 0]; eval $body}
every 100 {
    puts "I'm saying Hi ten times a second!"
}
```

That's the simplest form of `every`; more complex cancelable versions are further down that wiki page.